# Jquery get a reference to the inital node

Tags: jquery

I have this line:

```
$('.faq_answer').prev().append(finalRender.cloneNode(true)).click(function () {toggle(this)});
```

I need to replace the this keyword with a reference to the node in $('.faq_answer.') that is currently being operated on.

I have checked the Jquery documentation and it doesn't seem to cover this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
     click(function (event) {
      //event.target is the element that has been clicked and you could use this instead of click
      });
```

If you want a refernce to the selctor (which i didn't think you wanted so i deleted my answer), you can simply do this:

```
    var faq = $('.faq_answer')
```

Comment: wouldn't event refer to the appended node?

Comment: event should refer to the event triggered when you clicked on something. Like 'this' should refer to the element being clicked on.

Comment: OK. I want to be able to refer to the $('.faq_answer') element that was orignally used to find the approiate place to append the node, not the element clicked.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the context of any function, is scoped to that function. Therefore, you should first get a reference to `.fag_answer`, then you can use it.

```
 var faq = $('.faq_answer');
 faq.prev().append(finalRender.clonNode(true)).click(function(){toggle(faq);});
```

Answer (score 0):

As described by Nicola above, you can create a reference to the selector and then use it within your click handler:

```
var faq = $('.faq_answer');
faq.prev().append(finalRender.cloneNode(true)).click(function () {toggle(faq)});
```

You might also want to create a closure around it.

Comment: How would I determine which dom object in the Jquery object had orginally been used to append the node?

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found a way of doing this:

```
var faq = $('.faq_answer');
faq.prev().append(finalRender.cloneNode(true)).click(function () {toggle($(this).siblings())});
```

Gives me all the siblings of the current faq dom object.

Then in my toggle function I added:

```
element = element.get(0);
```

Which appears to get me the dom element I want to operate on. For the moment I'm assuming it is robust, but really I don't understand why it should work like that.